# Why is does proc_create mode argument 0 correspond to 0444

Tags: linux, permissions, kernel, procfs

I am a newbie to kernel programming and am trying to userstand procfs. I have googled several examples and they all use:

```
 proc_create("hello",0,NULL,&proc_fops);
```

where the second argument is the file mode / permission. Per proc_fs.h:

```
static inline struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(
         const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent,
         const struct file_operations *proc_fops)
```

the mode is umode_t type which as far as I can tell is resolved to unsigned short int.

In at least 3 examples, the accompanying comments and verbiage indicate substantially the same thing, that "  the value zero you see there represents the permissions you want on the proc file, where zero represents the default value of file permissions of 0444. In other words, you could have just used tt he numeric value 0444 (for octal), or 0400 for more restrictive access, and so on. But using zero for a typical readable proc file is fairly normal."

I'm having trouble understanding what this means. I understand file permissions, chmod u+x , octal numbers, and I think I understand umask.

I'm just not clear on how 0 maps to 0444, and what would happen if I put 1 there instead of 0.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not that `0` maps on to `0444`, but rather that `0` is used to signal the default which happens to be `0444`.

Comment: Anybody know why this was migrated?

Comment: Well, since this question is more about programming than about *nix, it *does* make more sense on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be only very little bit further. *include/linux/proc_fs.h* says:

```
static inline struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(
        const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent,
        const struct file_operations *proc_fops)
{
           return proc_create_data(name, mode, parent, proc_fops, NULL);
}
```

*proc_create_data* is defined in *fs/proc/generic.c*. And there it is:

```
struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create_data(const char *name, umode_t mode,
                    struct proc_dir_entry *parent,
                    const struct file_operations *proc_fops,
                    void *data)
{
    ...

    if ((mode & S_IALLUGO) == 0)
        mode |= S_IRUGO;

    ...
}
```

If mode is preventing everyone doing anything, set mode to 00444.

For completness, from *include/linux/stat.h*:

```
#define S_IRWXUGO   (S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO)
#define S_IALLUGO   (S_ISUID|S_ISGID|S_ISVTX|S_IRWXUGO)
#define S_IRUGO     (S_IRUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH)
```

and from *include/uapi/linux/stat.h*:

```
#define S_ISUID  0004000
#define S_ISGID  0002000
#define S_ISVTX  0001000

#define S_IRWXU 00700
#define S_IRUSR 00400

#define S_IRWXG 00070
#define S_IRGRP 00040

#define S_IRWXO 00007
#define S_IROTH 00004
```